# Python: No such file or directory even though file is correct

Tags: python, csv

I am having an issue with with opening a csv file in my Python script. I wrote a function that takes "filename" as an input.
First, I used:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';', decimal=','…)
```

without an issue. Then, I wanted to change something and opened it with this:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as datacsv
```

and got the "No such file or directory" error even though I was able to call that same file in the same script with my earlier code. So I know that my location and filename are correct. This leads me to think that I am opening the file wrong. I suspect it has to do with it being a csv file.
How is

```
with open(filename, 'r') as datacsv
```

wrong? How can I fix this? Thank you.

Responses to Comments: I am on MacOS Big Sur. I know the directory has not changed because when I comment out my new code, the old one works. Filename when printed looks like "~/Downloads/RawData.csv"

Comment: What does `filename` look like when you print it at the time before the `with open()` statement and before the `pandas.read_csv()` call? And what OS are you on?

Comment: May be your working directory has changed. Try `import os; print(os.getcwd())`, and see if the csv file is also in the same directory

Comment: A guess: `pd.read_csv` expands `~` as does the shell, but `open` certainly doesn't.

Comment: @WilliamPursell How should I call my file instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`open("~/Downloads/RawData.csv",...` will look for a file with that literal name.  Unless you have a directory named `~` in the current working directory, it will fail.  *Never* use `~` as a shortcut for your home directory except in an interactive shell.  You must expand ~ yourself.  Try something like:

```
open(os.path.expanduser(filename), 'r')
```

It's probably a better idea to sanitize the filename early:

```
filename = os.path.expanduser(filename)
```